# looping through a dataframe and extracting values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with id, value, missing values(this is a %age). I then want to have another column that has range that if the missing value is

- <=25 then it should return 1
- <=50 return 2
- <=75 return 3
- <=80 return 4

What best way can i do this

example of dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': ['1245', '1323', '1784', '1557','1456'],
'value': [11558522, 12323552, 13770958, 18412280, 13770958],
'missing value': [34, 56, 80, 5 76]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do so is to use the apply method as:

```
def RangeDefiner(val):
    if val<=25:
        return 1
    elif val<=50:
        return 2
    elif val<=75:
        return 3
    elif val<=80:
        return 4
```

And to get the ranges:

```
df['ranges']=df.apply(lambda x: RangeDefiner(x['missing value']), axis=1)
```

And the output for your input:

```
     id      value    missing value ranges
0   1245    11558522    34            2
1   1323    12323552    56            3
2   1784    13770958    80            4
3   1557    18412280    5             1
4   1456    13770958    76            4
```

Comment: works perfect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas.cut) to divide ur column into bins

```
df['range'] = pd.cut(df['missing value'],bins=[0,25,50,75,80], labels=[1,2,3,4])

      id    value   missing value   range
0   1245    11558522    34          2
1   1323    12323552    56          3
2   1784    13770958    80          4
3   1557    18412280    5           1
4   1456    13770958    76          4
```

Comment: works perfectly. thank you